# MS CRM 4.0 Security Architecture

Tags: metadata, dynamics-crm

Does anybody know crm workflow when i create some entity ?
I need to know where CRM check permission for Create, Update and so on. Is it in SQL tables and stored procedures or it's in CRMService ?

Answer (score 1):

All permissions are stored in the CRM Database, using Permissions, Roles and Business Units. If you want to check those roles, just open CRM, and in the Settings > Administration > Security Roles and you will see all the Security Structure.

If you want to directly view the security data, you can take a look at the database, but it's really hard to figure out everything.

Comment: Thanks. I want to know basic thinks: How CRM security workflow looks like ? For example: how privilege check occurs ? Is it in CRM Security service call, or CRM core call somehow some stored procedure ?

Comment: Do you want to keep the Mercure Integration account or the Churchy account? Please respond here and we'll perform the merge.

Comment: the Curchy Account, thanks! ... By the way, I had a lot of points on Mercure Integration... will this be merged?